# Время жизни кэша

Tags: redis, кэширование, postgresql, django

Пишу проект на Django. Есть пара больших запросов, которые я закэшировал в redis. Сколько времени хранить кэш, из чего исходить? В чем минус хранения кэша вечно? База данных(postgre) весит всего 50мб, в будущем может разрастись до гигабайта, можно ли хранить все в кэше и есть ли смысл(на сервере 4гб озу)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минус вечного кэша в том, что данные обычно меняются. "Классический" кэш с time to live позволяет не думать, где и как они меняются (а при изменении - где и как используются), мы просто говорим "если счетчик обновляется раз в 5 минут, а не в real time, нас это устраивает".

С другой стороны, Redis это не просто кэш, а довольно мощная база данных. Там нет ни механизмов связи объектов, ни контроля целостности, ни SQL, но зато работает она очень быстро и на запись, и на чтение, и поддерживает довольно сложные структуры данных в качестве значений. В некоторых случаях это оказывается важно, и довольно большие куски проекта могут использовать Redis как хранилище, а не кэш к "нормальной базе данных".

Если Вам кажется, что это Ваш случай - попробуйте, ничего же не теряете. При нехватке RAM всегда можно переехать на сервер побольше.

Answer (score 1):

Не следует устанавливать время жизни в бесконечность. Необходимо всегда устанавливать срок жизни объектов в кэше (это может быть день, неделя, несколько месяцев, но не бесконечность). Это позволит избежать засорения памяти и, как следствие, высокого показателя принудительного удаления объектов из кеша.

[Построение распределенной системы кеширования](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0QGFuq_M1g)